# Import OpenCV in Pycharm

Tags: opencv, pycharm

I want to use OpenCV (Python module) in pycharm. I set my Python interpreter in settings and added OpenCV path (`C:\opencv\build\python\2.7`) to the Python interpreter path. Unfortunately pycharm couldn't import OpenCV. It's noticeable that I see the `cv2.pyd` in the left panel (project panel).

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [How to install OpenCV on Windows and enable it for PyCharm without using the package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660114/how-to-install-opencv-on-windows-and-enable-it-for-pycharm-without-using-the-pac)

Steps to follow:

```
Install Python 2.7.10
Install Pycharm(If you have not done it already)
Download and install the OpenCV executable.
Add OpenCV in the system path(%OPENCV_DIR% = /path/of/opencv/directory)
Goto C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86 folder and copy cv2.pyd file.
Goto C:\Python27\DLLs directory and paste the cv2.pyd file.
Goto C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages directory and paste the cv2.pyd file.
Goto PyCharm IDE and goto DefaultSettings>PythonInterpreter.
Select the Python which you have installed on Step1.
Install the packages numpy,matplotlib and pip in pycharm.
Restart your PyCharm.
PyCharm now has OpenCV library installed and working.
```

If you have installed pycharm,then you can type :
   pip install opencv-python
   after satisfied,

then go to file ,setting (in pycharm)
   project ,project interpreter,click on plus icon on the top right ,

search opencv-python and install package.