# Integrating opencv with python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, pycharm

I'm using `Python 2.7` and `Pycharm IDE (32-bit)` in `Windows 10 (64-bit)`. I have installed `numpy 1.8` and copied `cv2.pyd` to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`.

when I import `numpy` it shows no error but after that when i import `cv2` it says: `module not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link [How to install OpenCV on Windows and enable it for PyCharm without using the package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660114/how-to-install-opencv-on-windows-and-enable-it-for-pycharm-without-using-the-pac/32664411#32664411)

```
Install Python 2.7.10
Install Pycharm(If you have not done it already)
Download and install the OpenCV executable.
Add OpenCV in the system path(%OPENCV_DIR% = /path/of/opencv/directory)
Goto C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86 folder and copy cv2.pyd file.
Goto C:\Python27\DLLs directory and paste the cv2.pyd file.
Goto C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages directory and paste the cv2.pyd file.
Goto PyCharm IDE and goto DefaultSettings>PythonInterpreter.
Select the Python which you have installed on Step1.
Install the packages numpy,matplotlib and pip in pycharm.
Restart your PyCharm.
PyCharm now has OpenCV library installed and working.
```